# Relationship between boost::exception and std::exception

Tags: c++, boost, exception

Suppose there is the following code:

```
try {
      // Do some boost stuff here
}
catch (const std::exception & stdEx) {
     cout << stdEx.what() << endl;
}
```

Questions:

1) I know that code works for some boost exceptions, even though std::exception and boost::exception are not on the same inheritance path. Why does it work then?

2) Does it work that way for all boost exceptions? In other words, are there examples when a boost::exception handler that is below std::exception handler can be triggered?

Comment: Without actually digging into the Boost code, I suspect that it has conditionals that defer to the `std` versions when run on an appropriate compiler, so they actually *are* in the same inheritance path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you said, `boost::exception` does not derive from `std::exception`. For the reason, check the corresponding [FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/exception/doc/frequently_asked_questions.html) :

> Despite that virtual inheritance should be used in deriving from base exception types, quite often exception types (including the ones defined in the standard library) don't derive from `std::exception` virtually.
>
> If `boost::exception` derives from `std::exception`, using the `enable_error_info` function with such user-defined types would introduce dangerous ambiguity which would break all `catch(std::exception &)` statements.
>
> Of course, `boost::exception` should not be used to replace `std::exception` as a base type in exception type hierarchies. Instead, it should be included as a virtual base, in addition to `std::exception` (which should probably also be derived virtually.)

The [recommendation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/exception/doc/exception_types_as_simple_semantic_tags.html) is to have specific boost exception classes derive (virtually) from both `boost::exception` and `std::exception`, and not just from `boost::exception`.

Some boost libraries' exceptions derive only from `std::exception` (like [`boost::bad_lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.bad_lexical_cast)), some from both (like [`boost::xpressive::regex_error`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/xpressive/regex_error.hpp)). I don't know of one that derives only from `boost::exception` though, so I'd say catching just `std::exception` should catch all.

Comment: How do you explain that boost::bad_lexical_cast can be caught by (boost::exception &) if the former is not derived from boost::exception?

Comment: @James : because [`boost::throw_exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html) was used to throw the exception, which enriches the exception - among other things by dynamically adding `boost::exception` as a base (for more details, click the link).